# How to save Excel file exported from datagridview in a particular folder with unique name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, sql-server-2008

I export datagridview to Excel. Now, I want to save this Excel file with unique name like date wise in a specific folder. And also I want to save the file without using save dialog file.

This code is used for only exporting datagridview to Excel.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application XcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    XcelApp.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                    }
                }
                XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                XcelApp.Visible = true;


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your excel file is populated correctly. You can use the SaveAs method like below:

```
XcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filePath);
```